# Information on new Windows 10 error: ERROR_CLOUD_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: c++, winapi, filesystems, ntfs

Running into a new Windows 10 error code opening a file for reading with `CreateFile()`. We get error **395**, but there is scant information available about what it means or how to resolve.  The details of the error from the Windows 10 SDK are as follows

- Error number **395**
- Error constant
  `ERROR_CLOUD_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED`
- OS error message **"Access to the
  cloud file is denied."**

The machine in question is Windows 10 Professional. It is running OneDrive, but the file is not located under the OneDrive folder. We suspect OneDrive may be using it's [Known Folder Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/plan-onedrive-enterprise#known-folder-move) feature

The code used to open the file is:

```
HANDLE hnd = ::CreateFile(fname,
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,
        NULL);
if (hnd == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    DWORD exitcode = ::GetLastError();
    printf("%d\n", exitcode);
    }
```

If anyone has encountered this issue, we'd appreciate any insight you can share.

Comment: just error returned by filter driver *cldflt.sys* (c000cf18). you try open file, system return you error and denied access to it. as is

Comment: You mean that using `Createfile` to access existing files on OneDrive is denied and error 395 is reported, right?

Comment: If possible ,the link you can refer: https://windowsreport.com/onedrive-access-denied-error/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After careful research, we discovered this was caused by a simple permission issue. The user process executing the `CreateFile()` call did not have permissions to access the file which was being stored in the cloud.  OneDrive's `Known File Move` had without our realizing it caused the folder to be stored in the cloud.

Once we realized it was a cloud-permission-issue, it was a simple matter to fix the cloud permission to allow the user process to open the file.

In our particular case, we arranged to run our process as **Administrator**, which allowed our call to `CreateFile()` to succeed. If you are trying to access a file stored in a OneDrive share that is owned by another user, then you will not be able to use this solution. You will need to ask the file owner to grant you the access you are requesting.