# DeviceIoControl fails with error 395 to set a reparse point

Tags: c++, winapi

Recently I posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63726513/cfsetinsyncstate-fails-with-error-not-a-cloud-file-after-a-file-update) and now I am trying to set a reparse point after a file modification with WordPad app. Currently I checked that the reparse point is a Microsoft tag and I can save the reparse point data in a REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER pointer before the file lose the reparse point. But when I try to set the reparse point to the file, after a file modification, I always get the 395 error with the GetLastError function after call to DeviceIoControl function using the control code FSCTL_SET_REPARSE_POINT. The error 395 doesn't appear in this [System Error Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) although I found this error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55419092/information-on-new-windows-10-error-error-cloud-file-access-denied) that has sense. I also removed the discretionary access control list (DACL) from the file, to grants full access to the file by everyone, before try to set the reparse point but I got the same error. Here I put two fragments of my code to get and set the reparse point. I will appreciate any help.

**Code to get the reparse point**

```
            HANDLE hDevice = CreateFile(
                filePath.c_str(), // File path in the computer
                0,
                FILE_SHARE_READ,
                NULL,
                OPEN_EXISTING,
                FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT,
                NULL);

            if (hDevice != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                size_t maxReparse = MAXIMUM_REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE;
                rdb = (REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER*)malloc(maxReparse); // rdb was declared as: REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER* rdb;
                DWORD outBufferSize = maxReparse;
                DWORD bytesReturned = 0;
                
                if (DeviceIoControl(hDevice, FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT, NULL, 0, rdb, outBufferSize, &bytesReturned, NULL))
                {
                    if (rdb != NULL)
                    {
                        if (IsReparseTagMicrosoft(rdb->ReparseTag))
                        {
                            wprintf(L"Is a Microsoft tag.\n");
                        }
```

**Code to set the reparse point**

```
            LPTSTR pszObjName = const_cast<wchar_t*>(filePath.c_str()); // File path in the computer
            PACL newDACL = NULL; // NULL discretionary access control list to grant full access to everyone
            DWORD secInfo = SetNamedSecurityInfo(pszObjName, SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, newDACL, NULL);

            if (secInfo == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                HANDLE hDevice = CreateFile(filePath.c_str(),
                    GENERIC_ALL, //GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
                    FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT, NULL);

                if (hDevice != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                {
                    size_t maxReparse = MAXIMUM_REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE;
                    DWORD inBufferSize = maxReparse;

                    if (rdb != NULL)
                    {
                        DWORD bytesReturned = 0;

                        if (!DeviceIoControl(hDevice, FSCTL_SET_REPARSE_POINT, rdb, inBufferSize, NULL, 0, &bytesReturned, NULL))
                        {
                            DWORD error = GetLastError(); // Error 395
                            unsigned long errorUL = error;
                            wprintf(L"Error %lu in DeviceIoControl method.\n", errorUL);
                        }
```

Comment: and this error for concrete file ? are you not try use another file ?

Comment: Hello RbMn, currently I am only working with two txt files and with both files I got the same problem.

Comment: this error can be only on some concrete file(s). in general of course how you understand no error on `FSCTL_SET_REPARSE_POINT`. so try set symlink for notepad.exe for example

Comment: RbMn for this problem I don't think so that was a symlink because these files don't point to another files and the error happen with Notepad and WordPad apps. It is a problem with the files rather than the apps.

Comment: you need test your code on some usual files

Comment: Thanks RbMn I will take it account, now my challenge is with these txt files and with several apps that can modify them.

Comment: you need at first do this on another files. set symlink for notepad

Comment: RbMn my app should run in many PCs with several apps to edit the txt files.

Comment: look like you not understand. first you need test your code, that you can correct write code for `FSCTL_SET_REPARSE_POINT`. where your app need run not play any role now

Comment: Actually that is my issue that I cannot set a reparse point with the code that I posted in my question, when I already have this reparse saved point in a pointer.

Comment: Is your sync engine under %systemroot%? The cloud files API always hides its reparse points from all applications except for sync engines and processes whose main image resides under %systemroot%. See [Compatibility with applications that use reparse points](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cfapi/build-a-cloud-file-sync-engine#compatibility-with-applications-that-use-reparse-points)

Comment: Thank you for your comment [Drake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10611792/drake-wu-msft), I tested your suggestion using RtlSetProcessPlaceholderCompatibilityMode and RtlSetThreadProcessPlaceholderCompatibilityMode functions, also copying my project to my %systemroot% directory but I still get the same error when I call to DeviceIoControl function with the FSCTL_SET_REPARSE_POINT flag.

Comment: I can reproduce this issue and I will consult this behavior with the related engineer, and any progress will be update here.

Comment: Thanks [Drake Wu - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10611792/drake-wu-msft) I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Seems that you've got [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64039538/10611792) by yourself, glad for that.